# View hidden files/folders using JSch

Tags: java, hidden, jsch, ls

I am trying to list all files on a remote system. To do this, I used an sftp channel to that system. JCraft channel sftp provides a Ls method which returns a list of files and folders, but not the hidden files/folder (starting with a ".").

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this method take something like a `-a` option?

Comment: don't think so.. here is the link to the api ...
http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html
there you can see the method Ls that takes the path as an arguement... there I have given "*" to get all files/folders.. trying -a throws an exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need to use the `ls` method like so:

```
sftp.ls(".*")
```

to get the "hidden" files.

Comment: Thanks, works great ! It seems very obvious now, had earlier tried "\*.\*" and I though that should do it. Anyway, thanks again.